# CMD command from Python, strips away SPACE

Tags: python, cmd, whitespace, space

I have a small problem when trying to run a CMD command from Python.

```
import os

quality = "source"
streamName = "wingsofdeath"

cmd = "livestreamer twitch.tv/" + streamName + " " + quality

os.system(cmd)
raw_input('Press Enter to quit')
```

When I run this, CMD removes everything after the whitespace part in the cmd variable.

It's supposed to read as this: livestreamer twitch.tv/wingsofdeath source

But it reads like this: livestreamer twitch.tv/wingsofdeath

So it removes the quality part.

If I remove the whitespace, it reads the quality variable. The problem is that I need a space to be between streamName and quality.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `subprocess.call(['livestreamer', 'twitch.tv/' + streamname, quality])` ?

Comment: Another option, escape double quotes in your `cmd` variable.  That way your whole command is wrapped in a double quote.

Comment: _But it reads like this: livestreamer twitch.tv/wingsofdeath_ - how do you know that? By CMD, do you mean the windows command prompt? Are you really running the code you've shown us?

Answer (score 0):

this might work

```
import os

quality = "source"
streamName = "wingsofdeath"

cmd = '"livestreamer twitch.tv/%s %s"' % (streamName,quality)

os.system(cmd)
raw_input('Press Enter to quit')
```

it will put streamName as first '%s' and quality for second '%s' for spacing in cmd the command must be unde double inverted commas and thus the string in python has single inverted commas too.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help, but I've tried this before.

This is the error code I get when I try this: 

TypeError: must be string, not tuple

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with "\ " instead of " "

Hope it helps.